# call to codeigniters controller function is not working

Tags: codeigniter, jquery

i am using $.post() to call a controllers function from view(though i know its bad practice) and in that function i am loading a view and its not working.

this is  HTML code : `<li id='files' class="active" >My Files</a></li>`

this is JS Code :

```
$("#files").click(function()
        {
        alert('hi2');  //just for checking

        var loadUrl = "/Fast-Docs/index.php/Docs/updatefiles";


        $.post(  
            loadUrl,  
            {un:"<?php echo $username?>"});  
        });
```

this is function in controller:

```
public function updatefiles()
{
    $this->load->model('DocsModel');
    $un=$this->input->post('un');
    $files=$this->DocsModel->getAllFiles($un);  
    $data['files']=$files;
    $this->load->view('files',$data);
}
```

Comment: What's not working?  You are not actually loading the resultant view via a `$.post` callback function.

Comment: Do you get your result back? You need them to display? Cause as I see now, your jQuery doesnt do anything with the result, like it gets the View youre loading from controllor, but dont push it anywhere on the page...

Comment: so what u guys mean to say i get my required page as a response to request and i have to work with that request and as i am expecting $this->load->view('files',$data); will not load the page automatically. right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually display your code after the ajax call, ie

```
$.post(  
    loadUrl,  
    {un:"<?php echo $username?>"}  
});
```

Becomes

```
$.post(  
    loadUrl,  
    {un:"<?php echo $username?>"},
    function(data) {

        $("#yourDiv").html(data);
    }
});
```